# Error in Webi when the language parameters change

Tags: translation, multilingual, webi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZyPZ.png)I got this error message whenever I switch the report langage from french to english in WEBI.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phz2A.png)
Can you please help me solve this problem ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you switching the language?

Comment: I have all my reports in french (their titles and column names ...etc) and they work perfectly. Once, I change language in preferences to english, I get the error message above.

Comment: I just added a link to a screenshot to my post ( so you can see, how I switch languages )

Comment: Do you have access to your SAP BusinessObjects support provider? I would raise this issue with them if you do.